# jack server is not running or cannot be started

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, pyaudio

I am getting the following error while trying to use pyaudio in python.

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyaudio
>>> p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
ALSA lib pcm.c:2267:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2267:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2267:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

It seems like the issue is specific to a version of pyaudio, so trying to update.
When I try to update pyaudio:

```
abhishek@vaio:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo pip install pyaudio --upgrade  
The directory '/home/abhishek/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.                               
The directory '/home/abhishek/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.                                      
Collecting pyaudio
  Downloading PyAudio-0.2.9.tar.gz (289kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 296kB 539kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Found existing installation: PyAudio 0.2.8
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (pyaudio) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.                                               
    Uninstalling PyAudio-0.2.8:
      Successfully uninstalled PyAudio-0.2.8
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-15VuRi/pyaudio/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-QGLaRp-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:28:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of PyAudio
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-15VuRi/pyaudio/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-QGLaRp-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-15VuRi/pyaudio/
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these messages are actual errors. PortAudio just "pings" all possible host APIs and devices and looks if they are available or not. This typically leads to a few messages on the terminal, which can be ignored in most cases.

If you want a Python PortAudio wrapper that doesn't print those messages (because it suppresses them for you), check out the [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.rtfd.org/) module.

Comment: The file `Python.h` is not found. You can get it by installing the `python-dev` package. But you don't need this, since PyAudio is already available as a pre-compiled package: `python-pyaudio`. BTW, you should consider using Python 3, then you'll need `python3-pyaudio`.